# How to extract a value from a json object as Data?

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to decode a json file however instead of just a straight up array of objects, it contains meta data. At the moment, my solution involves casting the data to a json object, extracting `results` afterwhich I cast it again to `Data` and then decode. It works but it's so messy. Is there a more straightforward approach?

My json file "itemsActual.json":

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "uid": "a019bf6c-44a2-11e9-9121-4ccc6afe39a1",
            "company": "Bioseed",
            "item_class": "Seeds",
            "name": "9909",
            "stock": 0,
            "average_cost": 0.0,
            "otc_price": 0.0,
            "dealer_price": 0.0,
            "ctc_price": 0.0
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "uid": "a019bf71-44a2-11e9-9121-4ccc6afe39a1",
            "company": "Pioneer",
            "item_class": "Seeds",
            "name": "4124YR",
            "stock": 0,
            "average_cost": 0.0,
            "otc_price": 0.0,
            "dealer_price": 0.0,
            "ctc_price": 0.0
        }
    ]
}
```

I just want to cleanly extract results with type `Data`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "uid": "a019bf6c-44a2-11e9-9121-4ccc6afe39a1",
        "company": "Bioseed",
        "item_class": "Seeds",
        "name": "9909",
        "stock": 0,
        "average_cost": 0.0,
        "otc_price": 0.0,
        "dealer_price": 0.0,
        "ctc_price": 0.0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "uid": "a019bf71-44a2-11e9-9121-4ccc6afe39a1",
        "company": "Pioneer",
        "item_class": "Seeds",
        "name": "4124YR",
        "stock": 0,
        "average_cost": 0.0,
        "otc_price": 0.0,
        "dealer_price": 0.0,
        "ctc_price": 0.0
    }
]
```

I.E. I want to do the following without having to first cast into a `Dictionary` then back into `Data`:

```
// What I want to do
let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: "items.json")
let resultsData: Data = data["results"]
```

Edit: Currently the code I'm using to achieve what I need:

```
let filename = "itemsActual.json"
        guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
        }

        do {
            // Load the json file with metadata
            var data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
            // Split up the string and extract only the value of results
            let str = data.asString().components(separatedBy: "\"results\":")[1].dropLast(3)
            print(str) // Printing here results in just the results

            // Convert back to type Data so I can pass it off to be decoded
            data = str.asData()

        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
        }
```

Comment: you can just query the results array?

Comment: That's my issue. In order to do that, I need to 1) Cast it into a Dictionary 2) retrieve results 3) convert results to Data. I was wondering if there was a more succint way of doing this and just straight up extracting the results array as data?

Comment: Nothing looks messy here. Can you show your decoding code?

Comment: "I just want to cleanly extract (as data)" what do you mean by "Data" here... You just want clean array list need to be printed??

Comment: @Kamran I'm currently out so I'll share my decoding code when I get back!

Comment: @Aditya I meant Data as in the `Data` type. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have done my research but none of them answer what I'm trying do to, not that `Codable` even has anything to do with it. I want to extract results as `Data` type so I can then decode that into objects, yes, but I already know how to do the latter. Its the former that I have issues with.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood you some but after reading the question again and some of your comments it is not clear to me how you expect this to work without first creating an intermediate object (struct or dictionary) that you need to then get "results" from? Is your metadata always the same? Is the data you want always in an element with the key "results"?

Comment: @Karmran edited my question add the code I'm using to parse out results

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm asking if it's possible but I guess by your answer, that's a no? I updated my question to show how I'm currently doing it. In my previous answer I casted it to Dictionary but I redid it as this seems to be a more efficient way of doing it 1) cast to `Str 2) Parse out results 3) Cast back to `Data` which I can then pass of to be decoded into a list of my structs. Yes and no. The meta data's values will change but the keys will remain consistent. And yes, only ever in result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the question here is "Why you need just the content of result's array?" 
You mention that you `decode` the array so I assume what you need here is just a wrapper container structure just for decoding, e.g. something like this

```
struct ResultHolder: Decodable {
     let results: [YourCustomType]
}

let resultHolder = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultHolder.self, from: data) 

//use your array:
print(resultHolder.results)
```

Edit:

I assume that all of your reponses from API (thats where the JSON is coming from, right) follow similar structure. So it is a good time to introduce generics. e.g. like:

```
struct ResultHolder<T>: Decodable where T: Decodable {
    let results: [T]
}
```

Comment: I need just the contents because I would have preferred to not have to make wrapper structs just to handle the data. With dozens of models, if I had to write a wrapper class for each, the app would become bloated very fast

Comment: You could introduce generics, or you could make wrapper data types local to the decoding function, so that it does not pollute namespace

Comment: Could I reuse the generic `ResultHolder<T>` with different models? Because that's what I need. If not then I would still have to write one per model which would bloat up my app. I'm trying it now but I can't seem to get it to work, apologies if I'm doing this wrong

Comment: Yes, thats the idea behind generics in this case. What is not working for you at the moment?

Comment: Oh I see. I'm probably calling it wrong then. I'll try to do more research on how to use generics and see if I can get it working from here. Thanks for steering me in this direction!

Answer (score 1):

```
let dataContacts = // your array or dict
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(dataContacts)  // converting to data
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest and general way to do it without any extra coding, if this is to much code for you then I guess the answer to your question is "no, it can't be done"

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
    if let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        let dataResults = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: results)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim, Not exactly the answer I was looking for but at least this feels more "proper" than what I currently have